# Vulkan swapchain image extent capabilities

Tags: vulkan

I am doing query on swapchain capabilities where I am checking on `currentExtent`,`minImageExtent` and `maxImageExtent` properties of `VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR`.

For window size of **128x128** I am getting:

currentExtent = 148x128

minImageExtent = 148x128

maxImageExtent = 148x128

But for window size **256x256** I am getting:

currentExtent = 256x256

minImageExtent = 256x256

maxImageExtent = 256x256

For **1280x720**:

currentExtent = 1280x720

minImageExtent = 1280x720

maxImageExtent = 1280x720

I have two questions:

1. Why for 128x128 the width is not the same value?
2. Why current,min,max for the rest of dimension are the same?

My hardware: NVIDIA RTX 3000, Driver version 431.86, Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Feels like a bug (yours, or driver).

Q2: Because it works like that on some platforms. See the [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-khr-extensions/html/vkspec.html#platformCreateSurface_win32), e.g.:

> With Win32, `minImageExtent`, `maxImageExtent`, and `currentExtent` **must** always equal the window size.